# Can we use Hibernate Search with MySQL 5.1 InnoDB in a JSF app

Tags: mysql, jsf, java-ee-6, hibernate-search

I am sorry to post such question here. I have no stack to show yet.
Before going deeper! I want to know whether it is possible to use Hibernate Search in a JSF application that communicates with an **InnoDB MySQL 5.1** database.
Full text search feature is only available for MyISAM engine and InnoDB MySQL 5.6.

If not possible. What do you suggest to implement a Full text search in such JSF Application?
Apache Lucene? Solr? Any tips? Any demo tutos?

The purpose is to give the end user a search input text and a search button that allows him/her to search data in different entities and siplay results in an xhtml page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate Search uses Lucene as its full-text search backend, and you can hook it up to a MySQL InnoDB database with no problem.  Essentially, your full-text search queries are run against the Lucene documents that Hibernate Search maintains, and you can still use CRUD operations on your current database.  See also the Hibernate Search/Lucene diagram  [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e663).